# fixed background-image for specific section on mobile chrome browser isn't working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-app

I know, this has been discussed over and over again. but it still seems to be a specific understanding issue on my side. after implementing several bug fixes from here and elsewhere my site is still not working as wished.
I got a fixed background-image in the header section of my page. this is working perfectly fine on normal chrome browser. however i cannot get it running on mobile chrome browser

i've got following lines of html:

```
<body id="page-top">
<!-- Header -->
<header class="masthead bg-head text-white text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase mb-0">My Name</h1>
        <img id="header-star" class="img-fluid" src="img/star-light.png" alt="">
    </div>
</header>
```

aligned with the following lines of css:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header{
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    background-image: url("../img/background-bern-4.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    padding-top: 6rem;
    height:500px;
}
```

[image]

for example i wrote a media query with height of 100% with browser specific commands and so on:

```
@media (max-width: 576px){
    header{
        height:100%;
        background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

and then i tried to put y-overflow: scroll; to body and hidden to header [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532327/background-attachmentfixed-not-working-android-chrome-v40)

Furthermore I tried to put the image into a div like this [enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/working-fixed-background-image-in-chrome-mobile-vs-performance/)
html:

```
<!-- Header -->
<header class="masthead bg-head text-white text-center">
    <div class="container header">
        <h1 class="text-uppercase mb-0">My Name</h1>
        <img id="header-star" class="img-fluid" src="img/star-light.png" alt="">
    </div>
</header>
```

css:

```
.header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    background-image: url("../img/background-bern-4.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    padding-top: 6rem;
    height:500px;
}
```

whit this technique the picture is gone completely after all
[image]

somewhere I must missing something, don't I?

Comment: 1. in your media query you have `background: url(bg.jpg)` - is this the correct link to the image? 2. `height:100%;` probably won't work. Do you want `height:100vh;`?

Comment: no it isn't was missing to xhange the url after several tries to fix it. i would like to have a static height in px

Comment: Can you recreate the situation in a jsfiddle? Or is it working now?

Comment: any chance i can set jsfiddle to mobile browser emulation? otherwise i can't recreate the situation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix path of background image

```css
@media (max-width: 576px){
   header{
    background-image: url("../img/background-bern-4.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    height:auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
}
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: tried, but it doesnt work. used the 2 points from the comment on my question which is working well =)