# Parallax main image div height won't scale on mobile

Tags: css, image, scaling, parallax

Finally got my main parallax image to scale on mobile with background-size: 100% auto, but now there's a large empty space after the image where the div isn't scaling down to mobile size. Please help! Here's the [site](http://midniteoilmedia.com/koport/index.php).

```
css

.bcg {
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100% auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.hsContainer {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.hsContent {
max-width: 450px;
margin: -150px auto 0 auto;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #ebebeb;
padding: 0 8%;
text-align: center
}
```

Comment: Using `background-size: cover` should work better in this case...

Comment: I was using background-size: cover, but then the image is ridiculously huge. Is there no easy way to make the div responsive?

Comment: You could use a media query to include a different background image for portrait or landscape. If the image ratio is fixed, there's no way that I know to get around it either showing the horizontal *or* vertical middle when resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

background-attachment: fixed; does not tend to be supported by mobile browsers. In my experience it tends to cause some undesirable behaviour.

This might help: [Background-attachment: fixed not working on android/mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664927/background-attachment-fixed-not-working-on-android-mobile)

In addition: I think the p tag is causing your problem. Inspecting the elements shows that the P tag is taking about 20-30px height. but has no content in it.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the p tag and nothing changed. Also added the overflow tag and it just made my text disappear. Thanks though!